# Where is the LITHIUM in NMC Cathode?

Tags: electrochemistry, electricity

This maybe a noob question, but regarding NMC Cathodes, it is said that 33% each of Ni, Mn and Cobalt. So where is the LITHIUM supposed to be if all Ni Mn and Co already make up 100%?

Comment: The lithium is present as ions that intercalate into the cathode and anode.

Comment: @Poutnik So from a Chemistry point of view, can you please give me an example of NMC Cathode. There what would be the weight in % of Lithium, when we are already saying Ni Mn and Co mixed oxides make up 100%?

Comment: This info is easy to be found, such a question should be rather closed due lack of own a priori explicit effort.

Comment: This info maybe easy to find, but it may not be very easy to understand for people who are not from a background of chemistry (or have been out of touch with school chemistry for long). Given that you have answered correctly, and I will of course close the question, it wouldn't hurt to be mindful of the fact that Stack overflow is a forum for asking questions, easy the answer for it may be. The added deprecative comment from your side just leaves a bit of a sour aftertaste for others who may not even ask questions seeing knowledgeable people like you for whom the answer maybe in the face.

Comment: Your question in its current formulation is better suited for sites like Quora, which, in contrary of SE sites, has practically no question policy, aside of inappropriate questions.  Questions containing (more or less) just a question(s) are usually closed on the SE network site for lack of own explicit a priori effort. [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). // As you originally accepted the answer, you understood it. So you would, if you found it by yourself, eventually asking for final clarification. At least trying is essential on SE,

Answer (score 1):

(Reusing my deleted comments:)

$\ce{Ni + Mn + Co}$ do not make 100%, as they are there in form of mixed oxide. Each 33% rather means they are in 1:1:1 ratio. E.g. for purely $\ce{Co}$ cathodes, the composition is $\ce{Li_xCoO2}$, with 0<x<1. The key is not to make x=0 nor 1, what would lead to irreversible changes.

In fact, it is formally mixed $\ce{Li + Ni + Mn + Co}$ oxide, where $\ce{Ni + Mn + Co + O}$ form an anionic lattice, while Li+ ions are intercalated within it, in variable amounts according to the charge state ( More charge = less Li, as it is moved to the graphite anode)

See also [Wikipedia: Lithium nickel manganese cobalt oxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_nickel_manganese_cobalt_oxides)

> Lithium nickel manganese cobalt oxides (abbreviated Li-NMC, LNMC, NMC or NCM) are mixed metal oxides of lithium, nickel, manganese and cobalt. They have the general formula $\ce{LiNi_xMn_yCo_zO2}$. The most important representatives have a composition with $x + y + z$ that is near 1, with a small amount of lithium on the transition metal site. In commercial NMC samples, the composition typically has < 5% excess lithium.

From [neicorporation.com: Lithium Nickel Manganese Cobalt Oxide (NMC) Electrode Sheets](https://www.neicorporation.com/products/batteries/lithium-ion-cathode-materials/#tab-id-8):

> Layered Lithium Nickel Manganese Cobalt Oxide ($\ce{LiNi_xMn_yCo_zO2}$) is a widely used class of cathode material with NMC111 ($\ce{LiNi_{1/3}Mn_{1/3}Co_{1/3}O2}$), also known as NMC333) being the most common representative. However, Ni-rich NMCs (NMC811, 622, 532) are becoming more and more in focus now in current research due to their higher specific capacity and energy. Among these materials, NMC811 ($\ce{LiNi_{0.8}Mn_{0.1}Co_{0.1}O2}$) can deliver a high capacity of ~$\pu{200 mAh/g}$ with an average discharge potential of ~$\pu{3.8 V}$ (vs. $\ce{Li+}$/$\ce{Li}$), making it a promising positive electrode material for high energy density lithium-ion batteries.